simple loft following a nurbspath
I searched, and read some similar questions, also watched some videos, but still can't figure it out.
I am trying to create a simple loft between two shapes (circles in this case) and follow a nurbspath, but the lofted object (bridge edge loops) stays straight, and jumps up to the top vertex of the nurbspath when adding the curve modifier, and selecting the nurbspath.
If I add sections during the "bridge edge loops" it makes an "S" type loft, no curve modifier yet.
What am I missing? Is it possible without some add-ons?





Do you just need to model some specific form, or are you asking about this loft functionality in general where the loft would have to follow some path defined by another curve(rail)? I mean, does it need to work with more complex cases than the given example?

One is trivial, the other one is a very hard riddle for geometry nodes experts.

if you want your tube to follow the curve, make it straignt and add some segments

@MartynasŽiemys Well, in this case is a simple one, but in others it might/will get complex. I wonder why there is no such one click tool, and complex geometry nodes are required.
I can easily do it in Solidworks, maybe I'll try do it there, and import it in Blender.

@moonboots Like said I did add segments, but it makes it an S looking shape.
I know I can manually achieve it with many segments, and dragging vertices.

again, your tube is supposed to be straight, otherwise it won't exactly follow your curve

Blender doesn't have loft along rails function. It's not implemented. Blender lacks other NURBS modelling techniques as well. It's not Solidworks. Same way as Solidworks doesn't have Grease Pencil for example or sculpt cloth brushes. They are just different software.
It's still trivial to model what you want, it just requires you to define the curvature another way. You could do it with a single middle segment after bridging edge loops straight and use subdivision surface modifier. Lower resolution circle is OK for that. You can go as low as 4 verts making it a square:


Loftng with geometry nodes is possible - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTgtrqO1llw

In the meantime I made it in a more time consuming way, I added more segments, and moved the various loops to get the curvature. I like your solution better.
I know Solidworks, and Blender are different, what I meant is that with all the genius at work to make Blender perhaps it could be a nice feature.

Blender is more centered around mesh modelling and this a function for NURBS modelling. There are talks/"executive dreams" about adding NURBS modelling to Blender amongst other things, however it's very uncertain and will not happen any time soon for sure. At the moment if you really wanted that functionality, Geometry Nodes is the best bet, but it's certainly not a trivial task. Mesh modelling has many alternative methods to reach similar results tough, in some cases they are even easier, in some not so much.
